# Styling select element (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, drop-down-menu

I tried some plugins but they all come with their own styling which takes quite some time to get rid of. Is there any plugin with minimal styling (or a really simple way) to apply custom background to select element? I just need something very simple.

Thanks

Comment: there is another nice link in [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one.  It even degrades automatically if JavaScript is disabled.

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery am using lines like this in my dom ready function :

```
$(".overlay").css("top","300px");
```

Goes like this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".overlay").css("backgroundColor": "#0f0");
}); 
</script>
```

.overlay is the class of the div i wanna change and then comes the css property and its value.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh sorry, my answer was pretty out of the topic. Just understood it now.